# Setting properties of aspx controls based in a generic List

Tags: asp.net

I get a generic list of all controls in an aspx page. What I'm trying to do with each element of that list is to set a value for properties Visible and Enabled of those aspx controls.

I don't know how to get TYPE from each element of generic list.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim controlList As New List(Of Control)
        controlList = AddControls(Page.Controls, controlList)
        For Each ctl As Control In controlList
            Response.Write(ctl.ID & "<br/>")

            'Here I setup property Enabled of control textbox1
            CType(Me.FindControl("textbox1"), TextBox).Enabled = True

            'I'd like to setup property Enabled of control ctl.ID, but how to invoke <type of ctl>
            CType(Me.FindControl(ctl.ID), <type of ctl> ).Enabled = True

        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function AddControls(ByVal page As ControlCollection, ByVal controlList As List(Of Control)) As List(Of Control)
        For Each c As Control In page
            If c.ID IsNot Nothing Then
                controlList.Add(c)
            End If

            If c.HasControls() Then
                AddControls(c.Controls, controlList)
            End If
        Next
        Return controlList
    End Function
```

**EDIT 1 :**

If I try to do:

```
For Each ctl As Control In controlList
            Response.Write(ctl.ID & "<br/>")

            CType(Me.FindControl(ctl.ID), **ctl.GetType()** ).Enabled = True

Next
```

I got error:  Type 'ctl.GetType' is undefined.

If I try to do:

```
For Each ctl As Control In controlList
            Response.Write(ctl.ID & "<br/>")

            CType(Me.FindControl(ctl.ID), **WebControl** ).Enabled = True

Next
```

I got error:  Cannot convert object type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl'

**EDIT 2 :**

If I try to do:

```
For Each ctl As Control In controlList
            Response.Write(ctl.ID & "<br/>")

            CType(ctl, WebControl).Enabled = False

Next
```

I got error:  Cannot convert object type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl'

I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Your AddControls() recursive function passes controlList ByVal not ByRef

Comment: Reply to your edit: why do you do Me.FindControl() when you already have ctl in your controlList collection? FindControl is not recursive but you're populating controlList recursively, so Me.FindControl() won't necessarily find a control that isn't part of "Me"

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to as Control (or WebControl) all have .Visible and .Enabled i.e. instead of using List<Control> use List<WebControl>.

However in answer to your actual question you can call object.GetType() which will return the type and then you can use either reflection to get the type name.

Comment: If I try to use: 
            ctl.GetType(), I got error "Type is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking, but since you're doing this in ASP.NET I'm guessing all your controls will fall under `System.Web.UI.WebControls`, so have you tried casting to a generic `WebControl`?

```
CType(ctl, WebControl).Enabled = True
```

All the UI elements of your page should inherit from `WebControl` which has both `.Enabled` and `.Visible` properties.

If you only want to do this for specific types, for example you want to loop through every control but you only want to disable textboxes and make buttons invisible, you could use `.GetType()` to find out the type:

```
If ctl.GetType(ctl) = GetType(TextBox) Then
    CType(ctl, WebControl).Enabled = False
ElseIf ctl.GetType(ctl) = GetType(Button) Then
    CType(ctl, WebControl).Visible = False
End If
```